# AWS Lambda limiting Python output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda which i want to run every morning showing the users with AccessKeys older than 90 days.  What i am noticing is that the return of users is limited

```
    import boto3, json, time, datetime, sys, pprint

sns = boto3.client('sns')
usernames = []
mylist = []

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::11111111:role/lambda_role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumedRoleSession4"
)
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
client=boto3.client(
    'iam',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    users = client.list_users()
    for key in users['Users']:
        a = str(key['UserName'])
        usernames.append(a)
    for username in usernames:
        try:
            res = client.list_access_keys(UserName=username)
            accesskeydate = res['AccessKeyMetadata'][0]['CreateDate']
            accesskeydate = accesskeydate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            currentdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
            accesskeyd = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(accesskeydate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            currentd = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(currentdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            active_days = (currentd - accesskeyd)/60/60/24 ### We get the data in seconds. converting it to days

            if 90 < active_days:
                a = str(username)
                c = int(int(round(active_days)))

                mylist.append(a)
                mylist.append(c)
        except:
                f = str('')

    print(mylist)
    finallist = ''.join(str(mylist))
    finallist = finallist

    sns_message = (finallist)
    response = sns.publish(
        TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:111111:sns',
        Message= sns_message,
        Subject='Access Keys which need rotating',
    )
```

How do i ensure all the users are captured in the python query and then emailed out via SNS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [IAM list_users() documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_users), you will see that results can be truncated and you need to paginate. The response you get back will include `IsTruncated=True` in which case you need to re-issue the `list_users()` call, supplying `Marker`, which you retrieve from the previous response.

Alternatively, and probably preferably, you can use a [built-in paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Paginator.ListUsers).

Comment: Thanks.  So if i am understanding correctly, 'users = client.list_users()' can be replaced with something 'paginator = client.get_paginator('list_users')'.  Apologies but i havent usd paginator before in boto/python